# How to make tiles with mirroring/gloss effect?

Tags: shaders, reflection

I am trying something that should be trivial, without success.
I've done a search and found a similar question, but I don't want to change the shader, I want to keep it simple and I think that what I want to achieve should be reachable with the simple PRINCIPLED BSDF node.
Yet, for some reason I can't make it work.

I have tried raising the specular factor, it had nearly no effect. I still don't understand what that parameter does, as I would expect an increase in... specularity factor. It doesn't happen.
I tried to play between metallic and specular, but of course this completely changes the way the tiles look.

Here you can see the shader and the result:
[image]

I just want to increase the amount of reflectivity of the tiles, so that the WC and bidet and the sink will reflect a bit on the tiles.

I also want to point out the huge difference with the viewport render, which shows reflection, vs the Cycles engine, which ate it all away:
[image]

Comment: Try turning up the clearcoat perhaps? The specularity changes the shininess, not the reflectivity. Roughness should make it reflective. Also, be careful increasing the metallic. Usually its just a 1 or a 0. If the material shouldn't be metal then don't increase metallic at all.

Comment: First, change the Color-Space of your normal map from sRGB to Non-Color and see how much that helps.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett doh, I did that, I don't know how that reverted to sRGB! Thanks for pointing that out, I was in fact wondering also at why some tiles were looking a bit odd.

Comment: @NascentSpace thank you! I will have to get info about the difference between shininess and reflectivity, I intuitively thought that they work on the same parameter.

Comment: Sorry, this may be obvious, but have to tried setting the roughness to something like 0.3 (keeping metallic at 0 and specular at 0.4-0.5)?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett why would I raise the roughness so much? Ceramics is one of the most smooth materials out there, for what I know. Raising roughness would mean the engine is not working correctly. However, I tried it now, but the result is not really changing much. I am also trying to calibrate the shader before introducing the normal maps, as these seem to wildly affect the rendering. One day I will understand on what the STRENGTH parameter is based.

Comment: This seems to be the best I can do: https://photos.app.goo.gl/fzGmiMBhWbuafxSC9  
Not really satisfied, but it can be ok for this project... I guess I'll have to take off a week or so to dig deeply in how this full-featured node works.